# BigQuery Standard SQL: pass INTERVAL, or date_part as SQL UDF argument?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to build a simple `TIMESTAMP_AGO` SQL UDF. The function is a simple wrapper around `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and [`TIMESTAMP_SUB`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#timestamp_sub).

I want to call it, with signature:

```sql
SELECT TIMESTAMP_AGO(24, 'HOUR');
```

or, even:

```sql
SELECT TIMESTAMP_AGO(24 HOUR);
```

But BigQuery does not seem to like the `date_part` of `INTERVAL` as a variable, so it fails. I've tried a separation of arguments:

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION TIMESTAMP_AGO(_interval INT64, _date_part STRING) AS ((

  SELECT TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL _interval _date_part)

));
```

and, trying to pass an INTERVAL as well :

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION TIMESTAMP_AGO(_interval INTERVAL) AS ((

  SELECT TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), _interval)

));
```

- Can `INTERVAL`'s be passed around like this?
- Or, is it possible to pass a dynamic `date_part`?
- Failing these, would it be possible to use an External UDF (JS)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

`TIMESTAMP_SUB` supports the following values for date_part:

- MICROSECOND
- MILLISECOND
- SECOND
- MINUTE
- HOUR

So, you just simply need to check your passed `_date_part` and use respective "version" as in below example

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION TIMESTAMP_AGO(_interval INT64, _date_part STRING) AS (
  CASE _date_part
    WHEN 'MICROSECOND' THEN TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL _interval MICROSECOND) 
    WHEN 'MILLISECOND' THEN TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL _interval MILLISECOND) 
    WHEN 'SECOND' THEN TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL _interval SECOND) 
    WHEN 'MINUTE' THEN TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL _interval MINUTE) 
    WHEN 'HOUR' THEN TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL _interval HOUR)     
  END
);
```

So, now below will work

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP_AGO(24, 'HOUR')
```

You can obviously add `UPPER()` to `CASE _date_part` if you expect case-insensitive input, etc.